# Mutt shows folders with permissions - how do I stop that?

Tags: list, permissions, directory, mutt

I'm using mutt. My problem at the hand is, that whenever I press "c" to change the folder and mutt allows me to press "?" to choose the folder I want to go to, it shows all folders complete with permissions. I don't need those. I'll attach a sample.

Can anyone please tell me how to disable the listing of permissions? Or at least, tell me what specifically to search on the web? Googling "mutt folder list permission disable" didn't turn up anything useful.

Thank you for taking the time to read and think about this.

Sample:

```
1     drwxr-xr-x  5 damait06 damait06     4,0K Sep 06 22:53 ../
2     drwx------  5 damait06 damait06     4,0K Aug 18 17:56 INBOX/
3     drwx------  5 damait06 damait06     4,0K Sep 13 16:13 INBOX.abuse
4     drwx------  5 damait06 damait06     4,0K Sep 06 22:48 INBOX.
5     drwx------  5 damait06 damait06     4,0K Sep 06 22:48 INBOX.
6     drwx------  5 damait06 damait06     4,0K Sep 06 22:48 INBOX.
7     drwx------  5 damait06 damait06     4,0K Sep 09 09:19 INBOX.
8     drwx------  5 damait06 damait06     4,0K Sep 10 12:57 INBOX.
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm officially too dumb to use a manual correctly. If anyone else stumbles over this: see [here](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html#folder_format) and make sure you delete "%F" from the string you put in your .muttrc